# How to write query to select dates from one table that are closest, but less than dates in another table

Tags: sql, ms-access

I have 2 tables in my Access database.  One table has a list of calls and call times:

```
|Start Time         |Agent    |
|6/7/2019 9:30:47 AM|Abandoned|
|6/7/2019 3:09:11 PM|Abandoned|
|6/7/2019 9:12:49 AM|Abandoned|
|6/7/2019 8:44:22 AM|Abandoned|
|6/7/2019 8:13:54 AM|Abandoned|
|6/7/2019 7:25:48 AM|Abandoned|
```

My other table has a list of users and when they changed their phone status:

```
|Agent         |StartTime    |Status           |
|Doe, John     |6/7/2019 7:09|Special          |
|Zombie, Rob   |6/7/2019 7:16|Available        |
|Buffett, Jimmy|6/7/2019 7:18|Training         |
|Buffett, Jimmy|6/7/2019 7:20|Available        |
|Zombie, Rob   |6/7/2019 7:27|Tickets          |
|Zombie, Rob   |6/7/2019 7:29|Available        |
|Buffett, Jimmy|6/7/2019 8:00|Training         |
|Zombie, Rob   |6/7/2019 8:01|Tickets          |
|Buffett, Jimmy|6/7/2019 8:01|Unscheduled Break|
|Doe, Jane     |6/7/2019 8:10|Unscheduled Break|
|Doe, Jane     |6/7/2019 8:14|Available        |
|Buffett, Jimmy|6/7/2019 8:16|Available        |
|Zombie, Rob   |6/7/2019 8:29|Available        |
|Zombie, Rob   |6/7/2019 8:32|Tickets          |
|Lee, Amy      |6/7/2019 8:50|Unscheduled Break|
```

What I'd like to find out is what status was each Agent in at the time the call was abandoned.

For Example: The abandoned call at 7:25:48 AM would be:

```
|Agent         |StartTime    |Status           |
|Doe, John     |6/7/2019 7:09|Special          |
|Zombie, Rob   |6/7/2019 7:16|Available        |
|Buffett, Jimmy|6/7/2019 7:20|Available        |
```

The abandoned call at 8:13:54 AM would be:

```
|Agent         |StartTime    |Status           |
|Doe, John     |6/7/2019 7:09|Special          |
|Zombie, Rob   |6/7/2019 8:01|Tickets          |
|Buffett, Jimmy|6/7/2019 8:01|Unscheduled Break|
|Doe, Jane     |6/7/2019 8:10|Unscheduled Break|
```

For the life of me, I can't figure out where to even begin on this one.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

You can join the two tables together and then get the record whose time matches the maximum start time from on or before the abandoned call:

```
select t1.*, t2.*
from table1 as t1,  -- only because MS Access does not support CROSS JOIN
     table2 as t2
where t2.starttime = (select max(tt2.starttime)
                      from table2 as tt2
                      where tt2.agent = t2.agent and
                            tt2.starttime <= t1.starttime
                     );
```